# Calculating DATEDIFF(Month) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datediff

I am using the `DateDiff` function to find the number of months between two dates. But I am facing the problem like if the difference is 1 month and 3 days it is not giving as 2 months.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(month, CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(DATE, '20/10/2013', 103), 120),
                    CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(DATE, '25/11/2013', 103), 120)) > 2
```

Result should be 2 but it is giving 1

The date column in the table is `varchar` type values are stored as `dd/mm/yyyy`. Even one day in the month should be calculated as 1 month

Comment: This should answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131958/datediff-rounding

Comment: Why oh why oh why? "The date column in the table is varchar type values are stored as dd/mm/yyyy." How do ever expect to sort?

Comment: no other way to get this done ?

Comment: even on the datetime field it is giving same result

Comment: Your assumption is wrong - the `DATEDIFF` looks at the item you tell it to - if you tell it to look at the **MONTH**, it will **ONLY** look at the month - and Oct 2013 and Nov 2013 is **1 month apart** - so that answer is **correct**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Answer

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CalculateNumberOfMonths]
(
    @date1 varchar(50),
    @date2 varchar(50)
)

RETURNS varchar(10)

AS

BEGIN

declare @days int
declare @months int
select @days = datediff(day,CONVERT(DATE,@date1,103),CONVERT(DATE,@date2,103)) 
select @months = datediff(month,CONVERT(DATE,@date1,103),CONVERT(DATE,@date2,103)) 

if(@days % 7 >0)
begin
set @months= @months + 1
end

RETURN @months

END
```