# Is it safe to use DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()) to get local SQL Server time zone offset?

Tags: sql-server

I read [datediff rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131958/datediff-rounding) about MS SQL Server and quickly make example:

```
select datediff(hour,'2015-04-15 19:59:59','2015-04-15 22:00:00')
go

3
(1 row affected)

select datediff(minute,'2015-04-15 19:59:59','2015-04-15 22:00:00')
go

121
(1 row affected)

select datediff(second,'2015-04-15 19:59:59','2015-04-15 22:00:00')
go

7201
(1 row affected)
```

There are a lot of recommendation (in blogs/SO) to adjust time to local by:

```
DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), DATETIME_COLUMN)
```

Seems that it is danger and result dependent on time where query executed.

Or there are guarantees that `GETUTCDATE()` and `GETDATE()` point to same timestamp if they in same query?

Comment: Your datediff issues have nothing to do with rounding - datediff merely measures the number of intervals that have passed. The difference between 19:59 or even 19:01 and a later time of 22:00 or even 22:59 would lead to the same result for hours, since in both cases, the hour of the clock has changed exactly 3 times. Your question about conversion to UTC is legitimate, but it does not involve rounding nor does it involve this behavior with datediff (which is not a bug and should not be considered as such).

Comment: So I suggest focusing on the main question and removing the first half of the question.

Answer (score 1):

They are not gauranteed to give you the same time however they should give you the time within a few thousandth's of a second. So odds of it causing you a problem (1 minute difference showing) are not very high.