# Calculate month difference based on dates SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, datediff

I would like to calculate the difference between two dates in months.

The problem:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mm, '2015-11-01', '2015-11-30')
```

The date difference returns 0.  I want to display 1 instead.  If the difference is more than 15 days then it should round to next month.

I tried using round and ceiling functions and division by 30, but it still doesn't give me the desired result.

Reason this question is different from "possible duplicate" is because I am looking for only month calculation based on Start and End date.  Also, my Start and End date structure is beginning of a month and end of a month instead of exact dates.

Comment: it is returning zero because, the date_part you specified is month, and there is no difference for month in your example

Comment: It looks like you want some custom date parsing logic and are unhappy with the default built-in normal date parsing logic.

Maybe look into counting the difference in Weeks and going from there?

SELECT DATEDIFF(wk, '2015-11-01', '2015-11-30')
SELECT DATEDIFF(wk, '2015-11-01', '2015-11-15')

Comment: (1) please spell out `month` instead of using lazy shorthand like `mm` (see [here](//sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx) and [here](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly/)) (2) `datediff` just measures the boundaries that are passed, since both of those dates happened in November, no month change = date diff of 0. If you want it to be based on days, use `DATEDIFF(DAY, ...)/15`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [datediff rounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131958/datediff-rounding)

Comment: You need to spell out the logic you require because dates have lots of annoying edge cases. In February for example (28 days) should it round at 14 days instead? Across multiple months how should it work? You could for example find the difference in days and divide by 15 but there are many edge cases to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Select 
     DATEDIFF(mm, '2015-11-01', '2015-11-30') 
     + CASE WHEN abs(DATEPART(day, '2015-11-01') - DATEPART(day, '2015-11-30')) > 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`SELECT DATEDIFF(mm, '2015-11-01', '2015-11-30') 
+ CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(mm, '2015-11-01', '2015-11-30') = 0 and DATEDIFF(dd, '2015-11-01', '2015-11-30') > 15) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE`

Comment: Please, just [spell out `month` and `day`](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly/)...

Comment: This solution definitely pointed me to a right direction, but isn't accurate.  Example:  Difference between '2015-11-01' and '2015-12-01' is coming out as 2 instead of 1.

Comment: @NonProgrammer I realized the error, and included the updated test for month diff being 0. I think that should do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still isn't working.  I think I figured it out by combining it with DATEPART based on your suggestion.