# Days difference between c# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following code in c#:

```
var days = (result.PasswordExpDate.Value - DateTime.UtcNow).Days;
```

`result.PasswordExpDate` has a value of 5/25/2019 4:49:37 PM
`DateTime.UtcNow` has a value of 5/24/2019 4:54:05 PM

It shows days to be a value of 0

In SQL Server I have the following and it shows a value of 1 for Daysdiff

```
DATEDIFF(day, GetUtcDate(), PasswordExpDate) AS Daysdiff
```

Wondering why the difference

Comment: Have you seen [datediff rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5132192/1115360)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because DATEDIFF counts the "boundaries" crossed (Midnights for `day`), and TimeSpan.Days counts the number of 24-hour periods wholly contained in the TimeSpan.  It's all in the docs:

> This function returns the count (as a signed integer value) of the
>   specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate
>   and enddate.

[DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> The Days property represents whole days, whereas the TotalDays
>   property represents whole and fractional days.

[TimeSpan.Days](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.days?view=netframework-4.8)